# Can I chain methods that do not return this?

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm starting with OO in JavaScript, and I have a class with the following methods:

```
 count(element) {
        return document.querySelectorAll(element).length;
}



 get(element, occurence) {
        return document.querySelectorAll(element)[occurence];
 }
```

The first method analyse how many elements of the specified type exist in the DOM and returns the numeric result, and the second works as a `querySelector()`, with some differences.

I would like to chain those methods with other methods. But as far as I know, methods must return `this` to be chained. How can I chain those methods?

Comment: Based on your code example I cannot see a usecase for chaining. Can you explain in your question how you expect the get and count methods relate?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you would envision chaining a count method and a get method? How would that even look?

Comment: I don't want to chain these methods with each other, but with other methods which I have not shown. If I could chain the get() method, for example, I could do the following using another method that I have created: `DOM.get('div', 5).add('p');`. add() would add a new `p` element to  the specified `div`. `DOM` is the variable to which I have attached my class.

Comment: sounds a bit like you are trying to recreate jquery. Perhaps you should look at jquery for ideas about how your own api should look. Alternatively just use jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, it looks like you want to build another DOM utility helper similar to jQuery. This probably isn't the best idea.

Based on your comment, here is an example of 2 wrappers that extend the behaviour of a node collection and a node that would allow chaining of an "add" method.

```js
class MyDOMNodesWrapper {
  constructor(elementSelector) {
    this.set(elementSelector)
  }
  set(elementSelector) {
    this.nodes = document.querySelectorAll(elementSelector)
    return this
  }
  get(elementSelector, occurence) {
    return new MyDOMNodeWrapper(this.set(elementSelector).nodes[occurence])
  }
}

class MyDOMNodeWrapper {
  constructor(node) {
    this.node = node
  }
  add(elementType) {
    return new MyDOMNodeWrapper(this.node.appendChild(document.createElement(elementType)))
  }
}

const DOM = new MyDOMNodesWrapper
DOM.get('div', 5).add('p').node.textContent = "hello"
DOM.get('div', 0).add('div').add("div").add("h1").node.textContent = "Deeply chained"
DOM.get('div > p', 0).node.style.border = "1px solid red"
```

```html
<div>0</div>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can chain methods whenever the method returns an object that has methods. For instance, you can write:

```
str = yourObj.count(".classname").toString();
yourObj.get("#table tr", 3).appendChild(cell);
```

You only need to use `return this;` if you want to chain methods that apply to the original object. This is generally only done with methods that modify the object; it allows you to perform multiple modifications with a fluent interface, like:

```
yourObj.set("foo", "bar").set("baz", "quux");
```

The `set()` method should perform the modification and then `return this;`.

If the method is used to return information, that's what it has to return instead of `this`.